# Is academic proposal ghostwriting ethical?

Tags: research, ethics

I wondered on the ethics of academic ghostwriting and withdrew from a paid contract based on the discussion here.
Now, the agency said they "understand" my position but asked if I could take up proposal writing instead.
So, is academic proposal ghostwriting ethical? Are you helping the owner to stimulate their thoughts or is is cheating also?

Comment: I have an inviolable rule when it comes to questions of ethics: if you have to ask *Is it ethical?* then you know that it isn't but are hoping someone can give you an excuse to do it anyway.  If you thought it was ethical you wouldn't ask.

Comment: Appreciated but not sure it's applicable. Thanks all the same

Comment: The situation here is this:, academic ghostwriting is unethical, you are writing a finished worked for another person--settled   BUT, in proposal writing, you are helping the client to shape their thought, help widen their horizon, the types of questions to ask, the scope, a review of the literature etc........ SO, is this ethical? That's what I want to know. Thanks!!

Comment: It seems to be the same ethical issue, just different ends of the con. There can be no doubt: if the proposal is accepted they will hire someone to ghostwrite it. –– however, writing *proposals* is the better job with clear 'wins' that might lead to strategies (assuming you follow up). One is just a paycheck, the other is persuasive writing skills put to use.

Answer (score 4):

I'm inclined to think you already know the answer to this question, as do most people in your "field." But for the sake of providing an answer, and because I don't get to write an answer like this very often, I'll indulge you by summarizing what you already know, and you can take it however you wish.

Let's review what an academic proposal means. An academic proposal is the first step for a researcher or grad student to produce a thesis or major project. It's meant to convince a supervisor or academic committee that your topic and approach are sound, to gain funding and approval to proceed with the actual research. As well as indicating your plan of action, an academic proposal shows your positioning and your relationship to past work in the area. Writing an academic proposal indicates to an authority or grant provider that you understand your own research area, that you can be trusted with money, and that you will provide your results factually and accurately according to the legal and ethical code of science. It is your pitch to a funding authority that you are knowledgeable, trustworthy, communicative, eloquent, and honest. ([Source of this definition, paraphrased.](https://advice.writing.utoronto.ca/types-of-writing/academic-proposal/))

Given this information, allow me to rephrase the question you've posed in a more honest light.

You asked:

> Is academic proposal ghostwriting ethical?

Now, you could spin this question with some leeway. When a professor helps a graduate student on their proposal by looking at existing literature and pitching them ideas, we don't call that "ghostwriting," and the professor is not writing words on the page for them - just helping their thought process. There is nothing unethical about a student seeking help and advice from others about how to write a good proposal, nor is it unethical to provide some guidance and help that stays in the lane of *only* giving advice.

Here's the fundamental difference between you and that innocent hypothetical scenario.

**You are making a profit off doing other people's work for them.**

Do not try to lie to us *or* yourself about that - you state outright that you take "paid contracts" in exchange for illegitimately produced research material, and either you're so incredibly comfortable with that fact that you're willing to admit it on a public forum just to solicit answers you already know you'll receive, or you genuinely think you can attempt to project yourself as "helping" people with a "service." Either reality is not in your favor. You are not a kindly old professor dispensing some pearls of wisdom, or showing the student some resources to guide their writing choices and research ideas. You are being paid ***money*** - cold, hard American dollars, or whatever your currency is - by lazy, morally loose students with too much money to spare who cannot be arsed to do things properly, and in exchange you are doing their work for them. Let's not try to play games about that. You can be as flowery and florid as you want about where your rent comes from, but to paraphrase an old professor of mine, "you can spray as much perfume as you want on a rat, but it's still gonna smell like a rat."

So, let's remove the facade and the cloak and dagger, shall we? What you're *actually* asking is:

> Is is ethical for me to take money from someone in exchange for writing their proposal for them, which could result in them being unfairly given grant money over someone else who *didn't* pay for my marvelous effort-saving service?

Or, if I really wanted to be blunt about this:

> **Is it okay to enable someone  to cheat if I get paid for it?**

If you need someone else to answer either of those questions for you, there is nothing else to say.

Comment: The answer clears it for me. You made some assumptions though, I just started working for the agency--anout 1 week or so, then the ethical questions came to mind. An internet search showed conflicting answers until O found this website. The answers here made things clear and I cancelled the contract  with the agent immediately.  Now, the agency asked if I'll accept proposals instead-- that triggered this question. So, it is from a sincere ethical mind who got tricked into an unethical practice without knowing it. So, it's not "my group" per se, I don't belong to that "group." Thanks Sciborg!

Comment: @QuintessentialFreelancer That's valid and I apologize if I made undue assumptions about you. I hope the hostile response could be excused a bit simply because this site is very anti-plagiarism and against practices like this, so when questions like this arise hackles tend to get raised even if the question comes from a place of genuineness. Good on you for cancelling the contract and doing the right thing.

Comment: No. You were not hostile--simply frank. I needed that level of frankness to make the decision. I just sent an email now cancelling ALL contracts with the agency-- thanks to your frank answer.

Comment: @QuintessentialFreelancer That's wonderful to hear. Glad I could help.

Comment: Although I agree with the majority of this post, I feel I have to point out that businesses and charities pay for people to help them write bids, which are essentially proposals. They don't have the skills and so they employ someone who does. Helping somebody shape their ideas into the format and style of the granting body is different to writing their proposal for them.I would also like to see all essay writing websites closed down and the owners prosecuted.